# Stop Image pipeline being called

Tags: scrapy

I am developing a Scrapy project to scrape product details and download its images from E-commerce website.

In phase-1
 I want to scrape product details only.

In phase-2
 I want to download images of scraped products.

But when i execute this command `scrapy crawl product` Image pipeline is also get called.

How i can do that ?

Here is my code:

---

pipelines.py

```
class ProductPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if 'image' in getattr(spider, 'pipelines', []):
            return item
        else:
            ......
            ......


class jellyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)
```

---

Product_spider.py

```
class ProductSpider(BaseSpider):
    pipelines=['ProductSpider']

    name = "product"


    def start_requests(self):
        ....
        ....
```

---

image_spider.py

```
class ImageSpider(BaseSpider):
    pipelines=['image']
    name = "image"



    def start_requests(self):
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: Pipelines are for crawlers, not spiders. Your `pipelines = ['image']` class variable has no effect.

Comment: So suggest me some way